# SQL Server Calculate Aggregated Difference in Data Windows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch some data from an SQL Server table by creating windows of 15 mins from the start time and find the difference between the MAX and MIN of a certain column (value) in these windows.

The SQL Table stores some telemetry data captured every minute.

Are there any T-SQL functionalities that I can utilize to get such output without running a loop (Windowed Aggregation sort, etc.)?

I have implemented this using a loop, but this is very slow as it would take data from every window and add it to a temp table. Below is a dumbed-down snippet of the code:

```
WHILE(@startTime <@endTimeInput)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #energyDataTable
    SELECT  MIN(timeStamp) as startTime, MAX(timeStamp) as endTime, ROUND(MAX (value) - MIN (value),2) as value
    FROM PLANT1.DATA_TABLE as ts
    WHERE ts.unixTimestamp>=@startTime and ts.unixTimestamp<= @endTime
    GROUP BY ts.logicalId
    
    --Increment startTime and endTime to goto next window
    SET @startTime = @endTime;
    SET @endTime = @startTime + 15 * 60000; --converting 15 mins to millisecs
END
```

| Timestamp | value | unixTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **2021-11-08 00:00:09.000** | **1527.6** | 1636329609000 |
| 2021-11-08 00:01:09.000 | 1528.1 | 1636329669000 |
| 2021-11-08 00:02:09.000 | 1528.6 | 1636329729000 |
| .... | .... | .... |
| 2021-11-08 00:13:09.000 | 1534.5 | 1636330389000 |
| **2021-11-08 00:14:09.000** | **1535.3** | 1636330479000 |
| **2021-11-08 00:15:09.000** | **1535.5** | 1636330509000 |
| 2021-11-08 00:16:09.000 | 1536.0 | 1636330569000 |
| 2021-11-08 00:17:09.000 | 1528.6 | 1636330629000 |
| .... | .... | .... |
| 2021-11-08 00:28:09.000 | 1542.5 | 1636331289000 |
| **2021-11-08 00:29:09.000** | **1543.3** | 1636331379000 |

Needs to be transformed to (I don't necessarily need end_time: Added for better understanding):

| start_time | end_time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-08 00:00:09.000 | 2021-11-08 00:14:39.000 | 7.7 |
| 2021-11-08 00:15:09.000 | 2021-11-08 00:29:39.000 | 7.8 |

Comment: Do you want the difference between the min & max values, or the difference between the first and last value in each group?

Comment: `@startTime + 15 * 60000` Bad habits are easy to develop and hard to break. Does the addition occur first or the multiplication? Don't rely on assumptions and default behavior. Make the logic explicitly clear to anyone reading your code.

Comment: Thanks, @SMor, so this was just a depiction like I said just a dumbed-down version of the real code. In the actual code, the calculation is happening elsewhere and the multiplication is not here. But I do understand your point. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows each 15 minute block along with the difference between the min & max value contained within the block:

```sql
with src as (
    select *
          ,chunk = datediff(second,min("Timestamp") over (order by "Timestamp"),"Timestamp") / (15*60)
    from (values
         ('2021-11-08 00:00:09.000',1527.6,1636329609000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:01:09.000',1528.1,1636329669000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:02:09.000',1528.6,1636329729000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:13:09.000',1534.5,1636330389000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:14:09.000',1535.3,1636330479000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:15:09.000',1535.5,1636330509000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:16:09.000',1536.0,1636330569000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:17:09.000',1528.6,1636330629000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:28:09.000',1542.5,1636331289000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:29:09.000',1543.3,1636331379000)
         ) src("Timestamp","value",unixTime)
)
select chunk
      ,start_time = min("Timestamp")
      ,end_time   = max("Timestamp")
      ,value      = round(max(value) - min(value),2)
from src
group by chunk
```

Result:

```
| chunk | start_time              | end_time                | value |
+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------+
|     0 | 2021-11-08 00:00:09.000 | 2021-11-08 00:14:09.000 |   7.7 |
|     1 | 2021-11-08 00:15:09.000 | 2021-11-08 00:29:09.000 |  14.7 |
```

If you want the difference in values between the first and last timestamp in each block, it's a little more involved:

```sql
with src as (
    select *
          ,chunk = datediff(second,min("Timestamp") over (order by "Timestamp"),"Timestamp") / (15*60)
    from (values
         ('2021-11-08 00:00:09.000',1527.6,1636329609000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:01:09.000',1528.1,1636329669000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:02:09.000',1528.6,1636329729000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:13:09.000',1534.5,1636330389000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:14:09.000',1535.3,1636330479000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:15:09.000',1535.5,1636330509000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:16:09.000',1536.0,1636330569000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:17:09.000',1528.6,1636330629000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:28:09.000',1542.5,1636331289000)
        ,('2021-11-08 00:29:09.000',1543.3,1636331379000)
         ) src("Timestamp","value",unixTime)
)
,boundaries as (
    select chunk
          ,start_time  = min("Timestamp")   over (partition by chunk)
          ,  end_time  = max("Timestamp")   over (partition by chunk)
          ,start_value = first_value(value) over (partition by chunk order by "Timestamp")
          , last_value =  last_value(value) over (partition by chunk order by "Timestamp" rows between current_row and unbounded following)
    from src
)
select distinct
       chunk
      ,start_time
      ,end_time
      ,round(last_value - start_value,2)
from boundaries
```

Result:

```
| chunk | start_time              | end_time                |     |
+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----+
|     0 | 2021-11-08 00:00:09.000 | 2021-11-08 00:14:09.000 | 7.7 |
|     1 | 2021-11-08 00:15:09.000 | 2021-11-08 00:29:09.000 | 7.8 |
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Had to google around and understand how this works, but this is exactly what I wanted! Thank you! You're a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

Data preparation:

```
declare @Telemetry table 
(
    [Timestamp] datetime2(0), 
    [Value] decimal(5,1), 
    UnixTime bigint
);

insert into @Telemetry 
values
    ('2021-11-08 00:00:09', 1527.6, 1636329609000),
    ('2021-11-08 00:01:09', 1528.1, 1636329669000),
    ('2021-11-08 00:02:09', 1528.6, 1636329729000),
    ('2021-11-08 00:13:09', 1534.5, 1636330389000),
    ('2021-11-08 00:14:09', 1535.3, 1636330479000),
    ('2021-11-08 00:15:09', 1535.5, 1636330509000),
    ('2021-11-08 00:16:09', 1536.0, 1636330569000),
    ('2021-11-08 00:17:09', 1528.6, 1636330629000),
    ('2021-11-08 00:28:09', 1542.5, 1636331289000),
    ('2021-11-08 00:29:09', 1543.3, 1636331379000);
```

And solution:

```
declare @StartTimestamp datetime2(0) = (select min([Timestamp]) from @Telemetry);

with N as 
(
    select n from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) t(n)    
),
Numbers as
(
    select
        row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as Number
    from 
        N n1, N n2, N n3 -- N n4, N n5, N n6
),
Dates as
(
    select 
        Number,
        StartDateTime = dateadd(minute, (Number - 1) * 15, @StartTimestamp),
        EndDateTime   = dateadd(minute,  Number      * 15, @StartTimestamp)
    from
        Numbers
)
select
    start_time  = min([Timestamp]),
    end_time    = max([Timestamp]),
    [value]     = round(max([Value]) - min([Value]), 2)
from
    @Telemetry t
    inner join Dates d on StartDateTime <= t.[Timestamp] and t.[Timestamp] < EndDateTime
group by
    Number;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d51ef/4)

Answer (score 1):

Generally we replace a loop with a tally table. For example on-the-fly tally

```
declare @dstart datetime = '2021-11-08 00:00:00.000';
declare @window int = 15;

with t0(n) as (
 select n 
 from (
    values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
    ) t(n)
), tally as(
   select row_number() over(order by t1.n)  n
   from t0 t1, t0 t2, t0 t3
)
select s.start, max(value) - min(value) delta
from tally
cross apply (
   values (dateadd(minute, @window*(n-1), @dstart))  
   ) s(start)
join  myTable t on t.Timestamp>= s.start and t.Timestamp < dateadd(minute, @window, s.start)
group by s.start
order by s.start
```